# why is my create function not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

just don't get it, I've been following a tutorial and it's just not working for me, can someone please help me figure this out? thanks

it submits and returns no error but nothing is actually inserted into the table.

SQL

```
  create_table "photos", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.string "content_type"
    t.string "filename"
    t.binary "binary_data"
  end
```

.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :photos, :photo, :description
  attr_writer :photos, :photo, :description
    def image_file=(input_data)
    self.filename = input_data.original_filename
    self.content_type = input_data.content_type.chomp
    self.binary_data = input_data.read
  end
end
```

controller (partial code) I'm thinking this code is wrong, it was auto generated. The tutorial didn't say this has to be modified.

```
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(:photo => params[:photo])

   respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @photo, status: :created, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

view

```
<%= form_tag ({:action => "create"}) %>
    <%= file_field_tag "photo" %>
    <%= submit_tag  "Save" %>
<%= form_tag %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in your view. Try to user `form_for` instead `form_tag`

```
<%= form_for @photo do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  <%= f.submit  "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

also your notation of `form_tag` is wrong. Try this

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "create"}) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag "photo" %>
  <%= submit_tag  "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you want to upload images I recommend you to look at this gem http://bit.ly/a3MJgN and this tutorial http://bit.ly/fGtvP3. Hope it will be useful.